# c# and stored procedures, unique code per SProc?

Tags: c#, sql-server, c#-4.0, stored-procedures

I'm writing an application which first connect to the database and retrieves a dt containing a list of all the stored procedures, inputs and their associated datatypes. The user then selected a SProc from the combobox and has to enter in the necessary inputs. The app will then connect to the database and run the selected SProc with the user specified inputs and return the results in a datatable.

What I'm unsure about is if I need to write a specific method for each SProc. I'm assuming so since I don't see how I could state what the parameters are otherwise.

Apologies for not making this clear the first time. Let me know if this still isn't clear enough.

Example is shown below (this is someone else's code)

```
public static GetDaysDTO GetDays(int offset)
    {
        GetDaysDTO ret = new GetDaysDTO { TODAY = DateTime.Now, TOMORROW = new DateTime(2012, 01, 01) };
        SqlConnection con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(@"Server = FrazMan-pc\Programming; Database = master; Trusted_Connection = True");
        SqlCommand cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
        {
            CommandText = "GetDays",
            CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure,
            CommandTimeout = 1,
            Connection = con,
            Parameters = { new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@offset", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int) { Value = offset } }
        };
        using (con)
        {
            con.Open();
            using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    ret.TODAY = DateTime.Parse(reader[0].ToString());
                    ret.TOMORROW = DateTime.Parse(reader["TOMORROW"].ToString());
                }
            }
        }

        return ret;
    }
```

Comment: If you are returning a table you should be using a function not a stored procedure.  Your question is a little unclear.  Can you elaborate a little more so I can understand what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is a design pattern called Factory and a way to tell which typed data table to create on each SP call

If you have the list of the parameters for each procedure, u could instantiate the Parameters object via a loop:

This class will be used to fill the params of the sp received from the db

```
class ParamData
{
  public object Data;
  public SqlDbType type;
  public string ParamName;
}
```

and then later on, when calling the sp, u should also pass thie ParamData object to the method, and used it to fill the params of ur sp dynamicly in a loop:

```
List<ParamData> list = new List<ParamData>();
//initialize command here as u did
SqlCommand cmd;
foreach (ParamData param in list)
{
  SqlParameter sqlParam = new SqlParameter(param.ParamName, param.type);
  sqlParam.Value = param.Data;
  cmd.Parameters.Add(sqlParam);
}
//execute the command
//fill the datatable with result
DataTable dt = GetTableBySPName("GetDays");
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
dt.Load(reader);
```

The only thing you need to add is the mapping between ur typed datatables and the returned table by the procedure. 

You can add a method to do this:

```
private DataTable GetTableBySPName(string name)
{
  DataTable dt = null;
  switch (name)
  {
   case "GetDays":
   {
    dt = new GetDatsDTO();
    break;
   }
  }
 return dt;
}
```

Comment: thanks for taking the time to reply. Im not familiar with the factory design pattern so it may be what im looking for but im not sure. The second code block Foreach(ParamData param in List) i dont understand how i can pass in multiple variables each with potentially different data types? or am i missing something?

Comment: Also notice in my Parameter class each parameter data is of the type OBJECT, which is the base class all the other classes in .net inherit from, and also the (for the same reason) the class SqlCommand's parameter accept as a value for the parameter.

Comment: Maybe i still havent made this particularly clear (sorry) or im being stupid :(. I already have the list of stored procedures etc in a DT and have populated the combo box. The code block i included in the original post, i have to explicitly state the parameter(s) "Parameters = { new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@offset", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int)" Im wondering if its possible to pass in an array of all the inputs so i wouldnt have to write that method for each stored procedure. Does that make sense?

Comment: You said u were receving a data table with all the procedures aprams from the db, and that this table included the procedure params types and names. What i did was simply adding a class, which (for every param) containts its name (that u can take from this data table u get from the db), type (which u get frmo the table as well), and later on the data the user fills, or u provide in any other way.
You already got all the information u need about the params in this data table u mention. the link you're missing is just wrapping each row there in an object with the additional propety for the valu

Comment: Yeah i think i get what u have done. Sorry for being a bit slow + thanks very much for your help, i really appreciate it!